# How to disable just vertical scrolling in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

UIScrollView has a property scrollEnabled to disable all scrolling, but I want to disable only the vertical scrolling.

Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

If the scrollView's `contentSize.height` is less than its `bounds.size.height` it won't scroll vertically.

Try setting:

`scrollView.contentSize = (CGSize){<yourContentWidth>, 1.0}`

---

*Swift*

`scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: <yourContentWidth>, height: 1.0)`

Comment: excellent answer. for some reason 0 doesn't work, but 1 does the trick. anything greater and the scroll view allows minimal vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(aScrollView.contentOffset.x,0)];

}
```

you must have confirmed to  `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
aScrollView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: This is a great solution, works for me. Here's swift 3 version:
```func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0)
    }```