# Disable UIScrollView vertical scrolling with NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

So I have seen the many other posts on this, and I think I have tried almost all of them. I don't want this to be a duplicate, but I can't get a solution to my problem. I have a setup like this:
 [image]

When I get to my Scroll View Controller, I can page over just fine, but I can also move the pictures around vertically. I think it has something to do with the NavigationBar forcing the ScrollView frame down, but still having the frame set to the full screen size. How do I prevent any vertical scrolling on the Scroll View View Controller? My .m is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

i = 0;

_PhotoBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".jpg"inDirectory:@"Dog_Images"];

_PhotoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_PhotoBundle.count];
for (NSString* path in _PhotoBundle)
{
    [_PhotoArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
}
for (int x = 0; x < _PhotoArray.count; x++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.mainScroll.frame.size.width * x;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.mainScroll.frame.size;

    UIImage *nextImg = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    nextImg = [_PhotoArray objectAtIndex:x];

    UIImageView *nextIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [nextIV setImage:nextImg];

    [self.mainScroll addSubview:nextIV];
    //NSLog(@"Pass %d", x);
}

self.mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.mainScroll.frame.size.width * _PhotoArray.count, self.mainScroll.frame.size.height);

}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What's the output of: `NSLog(@"self.mainScroll.frame:(%f,%f,%f,%f)", self.mainScroll.frame.origin.x, self.mainScroll.frame.origin.y, self.mainScroll.size.height, self.mainScroll.size.width);` in viewDidAppear?  Is it what you expect, or is it different?

Comment: ScrollTest[361:c07] self.mainScroll.frame:(0.000000,20.000000,460.000000,320.000000)

That is before I change the contentSize to 1.0

Comment: Interestingly it is the same when I do it while substituting 1.0: `ScrollTest[418:c07] self.mainScroll.frame:(0.000000,20.000000,460.000000,320.000000)`

Comment: Interesting... This would appear to be a ghost in the machine.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found a post that explained it perfectly:

[How to disable just vertical scrolling in a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535210/how-to-disable-just-vertical-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview)

When I change my

```
CGSizeMake(self.mainScroll.frame.size.width * _PhotoArray.count, self.mainScroll.frame.size.height);
```

to

```
CGSizeMake(self.mainScroll.frame.size.width * _PhotoArray.count, 1.0);
```

It makes the contentSize from being larger than the bounds... Something that I have read about, but did not fully understand. I hope this helps someone else who is stuck with this...

Answer (score 1):

`UIScrollView` scrolls it's content only if it's -`contentSize` is set bigger than it's frame. So when you are setting `self.mainScroll.contentSize` it has `contentSize.height` more that it's frame.

Try reading at least Apple's documentation before using it's classes. It's boring. But salary pays off all the boring stuff.

*By the way. You are using UIScrollView incorrectly for your displaying UIImageView objects. Try to watch Apple WWDC sessions (which could be downloaded from iTunes) - there are two or three sessions about how to use just three UIImageView objects to draw an endless UIScrollView paging*

[Apple's documentation on `UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: THanks for the answer. I have read a lot of the apple material and I am looking for the WWDC stuff in iTunes (so far nothing comes up). I am aware of the constentSize.height, which is why I think it might be linked to the NavigationBar.

Comment: I can't find the WWDC stuff on iTunes. Do you have a specific title I can search for? Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? I don't find this answer to be very helpful as I have already read most of the documentation and cannot find the WWDC stuff on iTunes. Thanks

Comment: well, here is a link for a WWDC session 2011: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/ and also you should be looking for "Advanced Scroll View Techniques" video session. Also you must have an apple developer program purchased for accessing Apple WWDC sessions. AND there's a session previous to 2011 WWDC - https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ (look for title "Designing Apps with Scroll Views")

Comment: After looking at the sample code and watching the videos, they are essentially doing the same thing. They still create the image views for each image, they just do a much better job layering. Although they are not using storyboard either, so I need to learn how to translate that and link it into Storyboard. Thanks for the direction.